# why the nested class will call the method of out class when the method not exist in nested class

Tags: groovy, inner-classes

```
class Outer {
    static void out() {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
    static class Inner {
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        //Intellij Note: No candidates found for method call
        Outer.Inner.out();
    }
}
```

After running this script, the `Outer.out` will be executed successuful. Why?
I get this info from the [official doc](https://groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_inner_classes):

```
The implementation of anonymous inner classes and nested classes follow Java closely, but there are some differences, e.g. local variables accessed from within such classes don’t have to be final. We piggyback on some implementation details we use for groovy.lang.Closure when generating inner class bytecode.
```

Anybody can explain why this script can be executed successful?

Comment: groovy dynamically looking for methods/members that are accessible for a context. method `out()` is accessible for inner class - this is correct for java: `static class Inner { static void inn(){ out(); } }`.  so, in groovy when you have accessor `Outer.Inner.` you switching context to Inner class where `out()` is accessible. maybe it's a bug, but for me it sounds logical ;)  you can always annotate your class or method with `@groovy.transform.CompieStatic` to get compilation error as in java.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This make sense. The official docs of java told me what the nested class can visit clearly. But the docs of groovy not explain this behavior clearly.